# JDBC and PostgreSQL - how to insert int in same row based on another int

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am working on my first personal project to try and learn some fundamentals of postgresql and Java.

I am trying to generate a randomly generated integers in a database with 45000 entries with int representing date and time using a for loop in the insert. I've managed to be able to do that part on my own and searching SX, but I ran into a problem.

If you can check out the code below, I would like to randomly generate an integer based on a previous field in the same row. For example, if my TIMEHST (which represents the hour of the time that a process starts) is randomly generated to be 8 on that row, I want my TIMEHED (which represents the hour of the time that a process ends) to be a random integer between (TIMEHST and TIMEHST+5). Please excuse me if the code below looks like spaghetti, I've only been coding for 5 months and Java for 1 month.

```
package generateSamepleDataSet;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 * Created by jkyju_000 on 2/16/2016.
 */
public class GenerateProcessSqlDatabase {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
                            "postgres", "adfadf12");
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            stmt = c.createStatement();

            for (int i = 0; i < 45000; i++) {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO ARRIVALS (DATEY,DATEM,DATED,TIMEHST,TIMEMST,TIMEHED,TIMEMED) "
                        + "VALUES ( " + (2012 + (int)(Math.random() * ((2015 - 2012) + 1))) + ", " + (1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((12 - 1) + 1))) + ", " + (1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((30 - 1) + 1))) + ", " + (7 + (int)(Math.random() * ((19 - 1) + 1))) + ", " + (0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((59 - 0) + 1))) + ", "I have no idea what to put in TIMEHED", "Also have no idea what to put in TIMEMED" );";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            }

            stmt.close();
            c.commit();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Records created successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the table description of `ARRIVALS`, including the data types of each column?

Comment: Arrivals has 7 columns, all int.
DATEY - year of the date
DATEM - month of the date
DATED - day of the date
TIMEHST - hour of the time that a process starts
TIMEMST - minute of the time that a process starts
TIMEHED - hour of the time the process ends
TIMEMED - minute of the time the process ends

So basically, I am generating a random data set with 45000 rows in the for-loop using Math.random to provide ranges of values to be randomized within. For example:

TIMEHST - can be any value between 7 and 19 hrs
TIMEMST - can be any value between 0 and 59 mins

Comment: So if I want my processes to take a length between 5 to 10 minutes, I would like to fill my TIMEHED on the same row as the value of TIMEHST. And I want to fill TIMEMED to be a random number between TIMEMST + [5 to 10].

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to learn about [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to pass parameters, instead of concatenating values. This will make your code faster, and, even more impoortant, safer and easier to read.

You also need to decompose your whole problem into parts, and code these parts inside methods:

```
int processStart = generateRandomProcessStart();
int processEnd = processStart + generateRandomDurationBetween0And5();
preparedStatement.setInt(4, processStart);
preparedStatement.setInt(6, processEnd);
```

Comment: As suggested, make a habit of using [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) rather than [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) to eliminate [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security risks. And it makes your code more readable as you can see in the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll check out how to write PreparedStatements and try to re-write the code. This is all new to me so thanks for the explanations.